# Hyperlink map on image with css

Tags: html, css, svg, imagemap

I have an image example:

[image]

this is a picture of desk with several elements, I'm trying to find a way to make parts of image interactive.

example - click on monitor, directs you to desired link.
speaker - different link

and so on.

The problem is that the solution must be in CSS and HTML with no use of JavaScript or anything else.

Is this possible?

So far I found only some sites for making interactive svg maps...

I know I can use:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EerkN.jpg" usemap="#menu_header" />
<map name="menu_header">
  <area coords="117,214,271,266" href="X" shape="rect" />
  <area coords="272,214,411,266" href="X" shape="rect" />
  <area coords="412,214,635,266" href="X" shape="rect" />
  <area coords="636,214,816,266" href="X" shape="rect" />
</map>
```

but I would like to use shapes that are exactly same as speaker, monitor etc. not just rectangle.

Comment: Is their some reason you can't use area tags and polygons?

Comment: Just use this page to make all the shapes you want: http://www.image-maps.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can use shape `poly` that come from Polygon.

> **Polygon**
>
> This expects as many pairs of coordinates as you need to make your polygon. These can make any polygon shapes you need, and can have
>   sloping lines. All coordinates are specified as horizontal position
>   then vertical position, with all of them in a long comma separated
>   list. The last pair of coordinates can optionally match the first. An
>   example would be:
>
> ```
> shape="poly" coords="217,305,218,306,218,306,228,316,243,316,243,325,229,325,229,322,217,310"
> ```

There are several [imagemaps generator](http://bfy.tw/3baT) tools online that can do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map generator tool to get `coords` for each `poly` easy and fast. I have tried this [Imagemap-generator](http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/). All you need is just drawing the areas you need to link (as I did here: https://gyazo.com/7ddba6578cd1ebfe4f31088d40f1cf06 ) and get the code at the end.

E.g. for speaker the code will be

```
<img src="url/to/your/image.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="80,895,134,855,194,813,239,766,275,726,319,669,364,647,397,645,442,666,476,705,501,746,513,805,527,856,550,921,578,979,608,1039,604,1107,584,1144,544,1185,454,1218,285,1216,134,1151,42,1033,45,944,174,824" />
    [...]
</map>
```